# i am getting error while giving my ip and localhost name in postgres admin

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am getting error while giving my IP address and localhost name in PostgreSQL admin, any help would be appreciated.

You can take a look at my PostgreSQL admin image here:

[image]

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'fakepassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it wants you to give the connection a name. Check the "General" tab for a field "Name" or similar and enter something there.

Comment: No, it's still not responding anything. i am getting the same error again.

Comment: ` 'PORT': 5432,` PORT must not be `''`

Comment: still i am getting the old error @cleder

Comment: Your django connection string is using different names to the pgAdmin. Does the user exist in the database ?

Comment: no, it's not. i don't know why i am getting this error. still i am looking for permanent solution. any help, would be appreciated.